# Student-Teacher matching problem

Tags: machine-learning, operations-research

[image]The problem I want to solve is as follows: I have data about how many teaching hours different students spend with their teacher in order to pass their exams. The teaching varies from 25-55 hours. In the school there are approximately 15 teachers and given a set of 10 student-teacher features that describe personality characteristics such as, age, sex, education, nationality, etc., I want to develop a student-teacher match model in order to minimize the teaching hours a student needs to pass the exams.

Any idea of what sort of algorithms I should use, or any examples I can look at?

Comment: Thank you.  Could you elaborate on what a "match model" entails?  In particular, is it intended to account for limited teacher time?

Comment: At the moment, each new-incoming student to the school is assigned randomly to a teacher. The teatching is individual (one student - one teacher). When the teacher is condfident, after x amount of teaching hours, that the student can pass the exams, the student takes the exams. If s/he fails, s/he takes some extra hours of classes and retakes the exams. For the school it's optimal for the student to pass the exams taking the minimum amount of teaching hours. Given some student features we want to assign them to the teacher that can prepare them for the exams in the minimum hours.

Comment: The data I have look somewhat the picture I added on the original post

Comment: This problem may be in the roum of Linear Programming

Comment: You could do something like make a description/estimate for each teacher how well they do (how many hours they need) for each student as a function of the student's characteristics. But it is a bit troublesome because the students might not need to be randomly assigned to the teachers (which means that the observed differences between teachers/students, might not need to be caused by teachers being more/less good with particular students, and instead can have other causes). Ideally you would set up a controlled experiment instead of use these vague data.